# Visual Studio Designer resize controls

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Dear StackOverflow Community,

on our form there is a UserControl created by us. The control itself works great. The problem is that the Visual Studio Designer changes the size of the control when reopening a form.

The control looks correctly as follows:
Correct Format:
[image]

With a new opening it looks like this:
Wrong Format:
[image]

The control has a min size set, can it be that the designer always adjusts the size of the control to its min size?

Best regars,
Christopher

Comment: could you provide some code with us so that I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: To be honest, there is hardly any code, it's all up to the designer.

Comment: you can report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for .NET.